# Why when I use QImage::scaled() I have a large memory expenditure?

Tags: qt

I write simple image viewer for education purpose. And the application must be able scaled image. For this I use QImage::scaled()

```
void ScreenImage::zoomImage(const qreal zoomFactor)
{
    const qint32 src_width = m_Image.width();
    const qint32 src_height = m_Image.height();

    QImage img = m_Image.scaled(QSize(src_width, src_height) * zoomFactor,
                            Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,Qt::FastTransformation);
    showImage(img);
}
```

After that I uploading received image in QLabel and shows him on screen.

```
void ScreenImage::showImage(const QImage &img)
{
    _pLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img));
    if(_pScrollArea->isHidden())
        _pScrollArea->show();
}
```

Question: why I have large memory expenditure when use QImage::scaled()? How I can fix it?

I recorded [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YBGLOiKVptQ) for viewing this issues.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the way you have implemented scaling.
Because you really do it (by scaling original image), your scaled image is pretty big and consumes a lot of memory (at least 4 bytes per pixel).

Also mind, that you display only small part of it, so most of the memory occupied by image is 'unused'.

What you need to do is not to scale whole image but only the part which will be shown to the user.

I don't have ready solution, but you can experiment with custom widget with custom painting which would present only desired part of image.

**UPDATE:**

Some extra hint which just came to my mind:
You can prepare custom `QWidget` which would set its size to size of the scaled image and put in into `QScrollArea`.

Then on the `paintEvent` you can use data from `QPaintEvent` to determine the area of widget which is painted (visible). This will let you calculate which part of original image should be extracted and scaled to match widget's visible area. This trick will cause that you will always use the same amount of memory which will be depending only on size of your window.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Thanks to your thoughts I has seen QImage::setDevicePixelRatio(), which doing what do me need. Now memory don't consumed is wasted.